# how to get data from database using django channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm trying to practice WebSocket implementation using django channels by querying the database and printing the data but I am unsuccessful.

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from .models import Chart
from chart.api.serializers import ChartSerializer


class ChartConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def get_chart(self):
        return database_sync_to_async(Chart.objects.all)()

    async def connect(self):

        data = self.get_chart()
        print(data) # <-------- I want to get this data
        # for i in data:
        #     chart_data = ChartSerializer(i).data
        #     await self.send(json.dumps({'number': chart_data.number}))
        #     print(chart_data)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        pass
```

Output

[image]

Comment: What was the error? What did `data` return? Have you tried `Chart.objects.all` like `Chart.objects.all()`

Answer (score 0):

You need the `database_sync_to_async` to be called in the `connect` method. Like so:

```
class ChartConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    def get_chart(self):
        return Chart.objects.all()

    async def connect(self):
        data = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_chart)()
        print(data)
        # for i in data:
        #     chart_data = ChartSerializer(i).data
        #     await self.send(json.dumps({'number': chart_data.number}))
        #     print(chart_data)
        await self.accept()
```

Comment: thanks for this. Do you know how to get data from the database and display it in the template without refreshing the page? For example, I added number 1 to the database through the admin panel and it will dynamically display in the template (no page refresh). thanks.